# Add body class to node in Drupal 8

Tags: twig, drupal-8

I am experimenting with Drupal 8.  I've created a local sandbox site and created a custom theme and a custom front page using Twig (page--front.html.twig).  I want to add some custom CSS that just targets the front page and I am used to targeting the body.page-node-x (Drupal 7).  In Drupal 8 I am having issues adding a body class to this custom page.  The only body classes I am seeing are toolbar-tray-open toolbar-fixed toolbar-horizontal.

Answer (score 2):

To add frontpage, logged-in and node type class for the body tag. Edit **html.html.twig** and add:

```
{%
  set body_classes = [
    logged_in ? 'logged-in',
    not root_path ? 'frontpage' : 'path-' ~ root_path|clean_class,
    node_type ? 'node--type-' ~ node_type|clean_class,
  ]
%}

<body{{ attributes.addClass(body_classes) }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have  need to add these code in " html.html.twig" template which you can find in core themes " classy" in drupal 8

```
<?php
{%
  set body_classes = [
    logged_in ? 'user-logged-in',
    not root_path ? 'path-frontpage' : 'path-' ~ root_path|clean_class,
    node_type ? 'page-node-type-' ~ node_type|clean_class,

  ]
%}
?>
```